# Ignoring errors on insert due to concurrent delete in referenced table

Tags: postgresql

I'm using "insert ... select ... where exists ..." to batch insert rows into a table while ignoring rows whose FK constraints are invalid. However, this doesn't work when there's a concurrent transaction that has just deleted a row in the referenced table.

Consider the following psql sessions:

Session 1:

```
coudy=# create table a (x int primary key);
CREATE TABLE
coudy=# create table b (x int, foreign key (x) references a);
CREATE TABLE
coudy=# insert into a values (1);
INSERT 0 1
coudy=# begin;
BEGIN
coudy=# delete from a where x = 1;
DELETE 1
```

Session 2:

```
coudy=# begin;
BEGIN
coudy=# insert into b select v.x from (values (1)) v (x) where exists (select 1 from a where a.x = v.x);
```

This correctly blocks session 2. However, after committing in session 1 session 2 now unexpectedly fails:

```
ERROR:  insert or update on table "b" violates foreign key constraint "b_x_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (x)=(1) is not present in table "a".
```

I would've expected the row to be filtered out and thus not inserted. In my actual scenario this is a batch insert, so ideally I want to avoid having to retry.

Raising the isolation level doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change session 2 to do the following:

```
INSERT INTO b
   SELECT x FROM (VALUES (1)) v(x)
   WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM a
                 WHERE a.x = v.x
                 FOR SHARE SKIP LOCKED);
```

The inner `SELECT` would skip all rows on which an exclusive lock is held because they are being updated or deleted.

That will not block or error out, but it may fail to insert some rows that would have worked just fine (imagine session 1 rolls the transaction back).

If you don't mind waiting for locks and don't want to miss these corner cases, you'd have to use `SAVEPOINT`s and handle errors with `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT` to avoid retrying the whole transaction.

Comment: Looking at this again, the lock totally kills performance - inserting 500 rows is now ~10x slower in my quick test. Is there any optimistic way of achieving the same result? It feels that should be possible given that I'm basically asking the DB to do less by letting it lose potentially inconsistent rows.

Comment: Locking the row will be some extra effort, but a factor of 10? The alternative, as I said, is to accept errors and use savepoints to recover. Maybe that is faster. You don't have to establish a savepoint for each individual row, you could set one every 100 rows and just redo these if you run into an error.